# Sending curly braces via PHP to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, braces

First of all, I know it's not how it's supposed to be. But the system has been setup like this so I have to try and work with it.

I have a column of entries in a mySQL table that look like this {12}-{32} and so forth. 12 is the id of the brand of a car, 32 the model.

Now I have to create a query in PHP where a part of it is like this:
`(PD1.fieldValue = '{". $_SESSION['carId'] ."}-{". $_SESSION['carModelId'] ."}'`

Guess what, that doesnt work with curly braces ofcourse. The SESSION part is completely empty (yes, they have a value outside the query).

Is there anyway to fix this so I still can send the variables inside the braces to mySQL?

Comment: Could you post your entire code snippet? I assume the code you have is inside a PHP double quoted string, but I shouldn't have to assume. It's also important what database API you are using. The answer to your question depends on this context.

Comment: Here a piece of it: `$SQL = "SELECT PC.id AS cId, P.id AS pId, 
   ... 
   FROM 
   PAGE_CATALOG AS P 
  LEFT JOIN PAGE_CATALOG_CONFIG AS PC ON(PC.id = P.cId)  ...
  WHERE 
   (PD1.fieldValue = '{". $_SESSION['carId'] ."}-{". $_SESSION['carModelId'] ."}'
   AND (P.productCode REGEXP '". $MAL_TYPE ."')
   AND PC.id = '1' 
   AND P.enabled = '1' 
  GROUP 
   BY P.id 
  ORDER BY P.productVolgorde ASC 
  LIMIT 0, 10";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself having trouble getting some characters into your database, that is a strong hint that your database code is insecure and vulnerable to SQL injection. You have to take a step back and look a little more broadly, thinking "What are *all* of the possible characters that aren't being escaped properly?" Luckily, you don't have to actually know. You just need to use the built-in escape functions.

The ideal solution is to use placeholders. The syntax depends on what database API you're using (mysqli, or PDO; deprecated mysql doesn't support them). There exist many excellent resources on how to use placeholders; [this is the first result I pulled from Google and it looks right to me](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Positional-and-Named-Placeholders-P551.html).

The somewhat less ideal solution is to use the `real_escape_string` function for your database API. Example for either `mysqli` or `mysql`:

```
// Using heredoc syntax, you can clean up your queries like so.
$sql_template = <<<SQL
  SELECT
    PC.id AS cId,
    P.id AS pId
  FROM PAGE_CATALOG P
    LEFT JOIN PAGE_CATALOG_CONFIG PC ON (PC.id = P.cId)
  WHERE PD1.fieldValue = '%s'
    AND P.productCode REGEXP '%s'
    AND PC.id = '1'
    AND P.enabled = '1'
  GROUP BY P.id
  ORDER BY P.productVolgorde ASC
  LIMIT 0, 10
SQL;

// For mysqli:
// $mysqli = new mysqli(...)
$sql = sprintf(
  $sql_template,
  $mysqli->real_escape_string('{' . $_SESSION['carId'] . '}-{' . $_SESSION['carModelId'] . '}'),
  $mysqli->real_escape_string($MAL_TYPE)
);
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
// For mysql:
$sql = sprintf(
  $sql_template,
  mysql_real_escape_string('{' . $_SESSION['carId'] . '}-{' . $_SESSION['carModelId'] . '}'),
  mysql_real_escape_string($MAL_TYPE)
);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at this time we are still using mysql and not yet mysqli. The query starts with: `$SQL = "SELECT PC.id AS cId, P.id AS pId, etc etc`. I will try and play some more with the quotes.